# Get content from ContentCachingResponseWrapper is always empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` to get my response payload and it is always empty on code.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcTagsProvider webMvcTagsProvider() {
    return new CustomProvider();
}

public class CustomProvider extends DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider {
    public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Throwable exception) {
        return Tags
                .of(super.getTags(request, response, handler, exception))
                .and(GetTagA(request))
                .and(GetTagB(request));
    }

    private Tag GetTagA(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String name = request.getQueryString() == null ? "null" : request.getQueryString().split("=")[1];
        return Tag.of("name", name);
    }

    private Tag getTagB(HttpServletResponse response){
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        String xpto = new String(wrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        System.out.println(xpto);

        return Tag.of("lolol", "lolol");
    }
}
```

This method is being called after `doFilter()` so I'm not sure why it's always empty because I can see the return from http method on postman

Any idea what is wrong?